# reactjs - Merge data with array using map

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native, lodash

React js newbie here. I could really use some help and guidance on the following problem.
First, I have db.json that consists of:

```
{
    "applicants": [{
        "id": 1,
        "firstName": "John",
        "lastName": "Doe",
        "email": "john.doe@example.com",
        "coverLetter": "Aliquam ut nunc eu augue volutpat porta ullamcorper."
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "firstName": "Erica",
        "lastName": "Hayfied",
        "email": "erica@example.com",
        "coverLetter": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus."
   }],
    "skills": [{
        "id": 1,
        "description": "PHP",
        "experienceInYears": 3,
        "applicantId": 1
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "description": "JavaScript",
        "experienceInYears": 3,
        "applicantId": 1
    }]
}
```

Currently the implementation below returns a list of applicants with an empty set of skills. I need it to return a list of applicants and their associated skills.

```
import { defaultMemoize, createSelector } from 'reselect';
import { get, filter, map, sortBy, } from 'lodash';

const getApplicants = createSelector(getApplicantIds, getApplicantsById,
                          (orderedIds, applicantsById) => map(orderedIds, id => applicantsById[id]));

* TODO: Actually merge related skills from the `state.skill` slice.
* @return {array} collection of applicants with their related skills included as a property.
*/
const getApplicantsWithSkills = createSelector(getApplicants,
                                    applicants => {
             const asApplicantWithSkills = applicant => ({
                                               ...applicant,
                                               skills:[]
                                           });
             return map(applicants, asApplicantWithSkills);
});
```

I’m sure it’s an easy solution but I’m stuck and probably overthinking it at this point. 
[Expected output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qlE5.png)

Comment: please share the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `map` over the `applicant` array, and inside each one and `filter` `data.skills` under the condition that `applicantId === id`. That will give you an array of matches, or an empty array if no matches.

Just to be clear, this output puts the entire skill object inside the array. You can modify what you put into that array as you see fit.

```js
const data = {
 "applicants": [{
  "id": 1,
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "email": "john.doe@example.com",
  "coverLetter": "Aliquam ut nunc eu augue volutpat porta ullamcorper."
  }, {
  "id": 2,
  "firstName": "Erica",
  "lastName": "Hayfied",
  "email": "erica@example.com",
  "coverLetter": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus."
}],
 "skills": [{
  "id": 1,
  "description": "PHP",
  "experienceInYears": 3,
  "applicantId": 1
 }, {
  "id": 2,
  "description": "JavaScript",
  "experienceInYears": 3,
  "applicantId": 1
 }]
}
const applicantData = data.applicants.map(userObj => {
  let applicantSkillObjects = data.skills.filter(skillObj => {
    return skillObj.applicantId === userObj.id
  })
  return {...userObj, skills: applicantSkillObjects}
})

console.log(applicantData)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working Demo**

```js
var jsonObj = {
 "applicants": [{
  "id": 1,
  "firstName": "John",
  "lastName": "Doe",
  "email": "john.doe@example.com",
  "coverLetter": "Aliquam ut nunc eu augue volutpat porta ullamcorper."
  }, {
  "id": 2,
  "firstName": "Erica",
  "lastName": "Hayfied",
  "email": "erica@example.com",
  "coverLetter": "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus."
}],
 "skills": [{
  "id": 1,
  "description": "PHP",
  "experienceInYears": 3,
  "applicantId": 1
 }, {
  "id": 2,
  "description": "JavaScript",
  "experienceInYears": 3,
  "applicantId": 1
 }]
 };
 
let res = jsonObj.applicants.map(userDetails => {
   let skillArr = jsonObj.skills.filter(skillDetails => {
    return userDetails.id === skillDetails.applicantId
  })
  return { user: userDetails.firstName + ' ' + userDetails.firstName, skills: skillArr.map(item => item.description).join()}  
 });
 
console.log(res);
```